# PhoneGap Error: EPERM: Operation not permitted (windows 10)

Tags: windows, cordova

I use Windows 10...

When creating the phonegap project using Phonegap CLI,
i got this error:

```
C:\phonegap_project>phonegap create pgexp
Creating a new cordova project.

Downloading hello-world-template library for www...

Download complete

shell.js: internal error

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Syamsoul\.cordova\lib\tmp\tmp_hello-world-template_1752_1454644396517\phonegap-app-hello-world-master\www' -> 'C:\Users\Syamsoul\.cordova\lib\www\hello-world-template\master\www'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:729:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\mv.js:77:8
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object._mv (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\mv.js:53:11)
    at Object.mv (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:186:23)
    at Extract.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\lazy_load.js:280:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
    at Extract.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at DirWriter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\tar\lib\extract.js:70:8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanna share my solution after days finding the solution.

I solved the problem by deleting the `lib` folder in

> C:\Users\{USER'S NAME}\.cordova

just delete the `lib` folder and try create your phonegap project again